# increase descrease nth child through var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have declared a var, each time I click first button, I want the first child to be yellow, then the next... and the other button must do the opposite, remove the yellow from the last element with yellow. how can i make this work?

**http://jsfiddle.net/XZyFW/10/**

```
<button id="button1">increase yellow</button>

<div id="container">
    <div>Hello 1</div>
    <div>Hello 2</div>
    <div>Hello 3</div>
    <div>Hello 4</div>
    <div>Hello 5</div>
</div>

<button id="button2">decrease yellow</button>
```

here is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var i = 1;

  $("#button1").click(function(){
      if (i > 5)
      {
          return false;
      }
      else
      {
          $("#container div:nth-child(i)").css("background-color","yellow");
          i++;
      }
  });

  $("#button2").click(function(){
      if (i < 1)
      {
          return false;
      }
      else
      {
          $("#container div:nth-child(i)").css("background-color","white");
          i--;
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XZyFW/11/

You're using `"nth-child(i)"`, when you want to add the *variable* i the the string. Instead use `"nth-child("+i+")"`.

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation:

```
$("#container div:nth-child(" + i + ")")
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var i = 1;

  $("#button1").click(function(){
      if (i > 5)
      {
          return false;
      }
      else
      {
          $("#container div:nth-child("+i+")").css("background-color","yellow");
          i++;
      }
  });

  $("#button2").click(function(){
      if (i < 1)
      {
          return false;
      }
      else
      {
          $("#container div:nth-child("+i+")").css("background-color","white");
          i--;
      }
  });

});
```